# React redirect after form submit doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, formik

I'm using redux for state management and formik for forms. I want user to redirect to a page if there's no errors with the submission but it doesn't wait for the request to complete it just redirect to the page immediately after the submission.

```
export const editService = (
  serviceId: string,
  body: ServiceCreateType,
  serviceImage: File
) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: EDIT_SERVICE });
    const config = await axiosConfig('ownerAccessToken');
    await axios.put(`${API_URL}/services/${serviceId}`, body, config);
    if (serviceImage) {
      await dispatch(uploadServiceImageForOwner(serviceId, serviceImage));
    }
    dispatch({
      type: EDIT_SERVICE_SUCCESS,
      payload: 'Service Edited successfully',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: EDIT_SERVICE_FAILED, payload: getErrorMessage(error) });
  }
};
```

I want user to be redirected if `serviceError` is null

```
onSubmit={async values => {
        await dispatch(
          editService(
            service.serviceId,
            {
              ...values,
              price: machinePrice(price),
              durationMinutes: durationOnMinutes,
              expertUserId: assignedExpertId,
            },
            serviceImage
          )
        );
        if (!isLoading && !servicesError) {
            router.push(
              '/dashboard/expert/[expertname]?view=my-services&type=pending',
              `/dashboard/expert/${userProfile?.expertProfile.name}?view=my-services&type=pending`
            );
        }
      }}
```

Comment: in your `editService` action does it return a promise? Update the question with `editService` function as well

Comment: I added the `editService` function. @AmilaSenadheera

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
export const editService = (
    serviceId: string,
    body: ServiceCreateType,
    serviceImage: File) =>
    dispatch => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          (async () => {
            try {
                dispatch({ type: EDIT_SERVICE });
                const config = await axiosConfig("ownerAccessToken");
                await axios.put(`${API_URL}/services/${serviceId}`, body, config);
                if (serviceImage) {
                    await dispatch(uploadServiceImageForOwner(serviceId, serviceImage));
                }
                dispatch({
                    type: EDIT_SERVICE_SUCCESS,
                    payload: "Service Edited successfully"
                });
                resolve();
            } catch (error) {
                dispatch({
                    type: EDIT_SERVICE_FAILED,
                    payload: getErrorMessage(error)
                });
                resolve();
            }
          })();
        });
    };
```

Comment: `Promise executor functions should not be async.`

Comment: `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. Did you forget to include 'void' in your type argument to 'Promise'?` it throws these errors

Comment: have you checked `!isLoading && !servicesError` these putting a log?

Comment: yes it doesn't even show, Do I have to remove async await from the submit function